# Distribution for the norm of a multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be random variable following a multivariate Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$. Do we know the distribution for its norm $r = ||X||_2 = \sqrt{X^\top X}$?

I understand that $X^\top X$ follows a generalized chi-squared distribution, but I can't find the distribution for $\sqrt{X^\top X}$. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: If you know the distribution of a random variable $\xi=X^T X\ge 0$ then you know the distribution of $\sqrt{\xi}$ as this is a monotone transformation of a continuous random variable, see e.g. https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf